# from vanilla javascript into react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to use [leafletTimeDimension](https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension) into react but I wanna convert it into react hooks to be easy to work with, I have problem understanding how to write this code into react:

```js
var geoJSONLayer = L.geoJSON(data, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latLng) {
            if (feature.properties.hasOwnProperty('last')) {
                return new L.Marker(latLng, {
                    icon: icon
                });
            }
            return L.circleMarker(latLng);
        }
    });
var geoJSONTDLayer = L.timeDimension.layer.geoJson(geoJSONLayer, {
        updateTimeDimension: true,
        duration: 'PT2M',
        updateTimeDimensionMode: 'replace',
        addlastPoint: true
    });
```

The problem is that I don't know how effectively pass reference to sub element

Comment: show your attempt of the hook you want to create, and we improve on it.